# Error while listing or creating an image in Openstack

Tags: openstack, devstack, openstack-glance

I have a fresh installation of Openstack on Ubuntu 16.04, through Devstack.

I run

> glance image-list

But i get this error :

> An auth plugin is required to determine endpoint URL

PS : the error persists even when i run the openrc-admin.sh file.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If your cloud host uses a self signed cert, it will not authenticate.   Add "--insecure" after the glance command to see if it resolves the issue.